# Prove T(n) = nlgn for recurrence T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n for 2^k k > 0 and T(n) = 2 for n = 2

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

I think I've proved this correctly, but I'm still a little fuzzy on some of the steps I've taken.

**Base Case:**

If $n = 2$,

$T(2) = 2 lg 2$

**Inductive Hypothesis:**

Assume that if $n = 2^k$ and $k > 1$, then $T(n) = n lg n$

**Apply Axiom of Induction:**

If $n = 2^{k+1}$ and $k > 1$, then:

$T(n) = 2T(\frac{2^{k+1}}{2}) + 2^{k+1}$

$= 2T(2^k) + 2^{k+1}$

$= 2(2^klg2^k) + 2^{k+1}$

$= 2^{k+1}((lg2^k) + 1)$

$= 2^{k+1}lg2^{k+1}$

How exactly does the following step work?

From:

$= 2T(2^k) + 2^{k+1}$

To:

$= 2(2^klg2^k) + 2^{k+1}$

Comment: I corrected "$T(2k)$" to "$T(2^k)$" in two places, one being where you asked your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected your question
so it now reads this:

How exactly does the following step work?

From:

$T(2^{k+1})= 2T(2^k) + 2^{k+1}$

To:

$= 2(2^klg2^k) + 2^{k+1}$

When written correctly like this,
it should now be clear.

You are assuming that
$T(2^k) = 2^k \lg(2^k)$
and this allow this to be shown
for $T(2^{k+1})$.